# Random solution for capacitated vehcle routing problem (cvrp)

Tags: vehicle-routing, metaheuristics

I'm currently solving the **capacitated vehicle routing problem (cvrp)** with the
approached methods (metaheuristics).

In order to do this I have to build a **random initial solution**.

My question is when we say a random solution it means that we have to solve it without respecting the **capacity constraint** or what?

**EDIT**

I'm using the following code :

```
public void RandomInitializer() {
    VrpProblem problem = this.getProblem();
    List<List<Integer>> routes = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    routes = this.getRoutes();
    HashSet<Integer> remainingNodes = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < problem.getNumRames(); i++) {
        remainingNodes.add(i);
    }
    for (List<Integer> route : routes) {
        for (Integer node : route) {
            remainingNodes.remove(node);
        }
    }
    List<Integer> curRoute = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    routes.add(curRoute);
    
    int curNodeId = -1;

    int remCapacity = problem.getVehicleCapacity();
    while (remainingNodes.size() > 0) {
        Number[] ret = findNode(curNodeId, remCapacity, remainingNodes, problem);

        int nextNodeId = (Integer) ret[0];
        if (nextNodeId != -1) {
            remainingNodes.remove(nextNodeId);
            curRoute.add(nextNodeId);
            curNodeId = nextNodeId;
            remCapacity -= problem.getDemands()[nextNodeId];
        } else {
            curRoute = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            routes.add(curRoute);
            curNodeId = -1;
            remCapacity = problem.getVehicleCapacity();
        }
    }

    this.setRoutes(routes);
    this.setNumLocomotives(routes.size());
}

private Number[] findNode(int curLastId, int remCapacity, HashSet<Integer> remainingNodes, VrpProblem problem) {
    int[] demands = problem.getDemands();

    double[][] times = problem.getRameTimes();
    double[] timesFromDepot = problem.getTimesFromMultimodal();

    int bestNodeId = -1;
    Iterator<Integer> iter = remainingNodes.iterator();

         while (iter.hasNext()) {
          int nodeId = iter.next();
          
          if (demands[nodeId] > remCapacity) {
                continue;
            }
        
            bestNodeId = nodeId;
           
        }

    return new Number[] { new Integer(bestNodeId) };
}}
```

But when I run my program `several times` I get the **`same solution`** is this normal since I proceed randomly?

Answer (score 7):

"Random solution" means the decision variables are chosen randomly. It does not usually mean ignoring feasibility constraints. So, in the case of CVRP, it would mean choosing the cities for a given route, as well as their sequence on the route, randomly. There are various ways to deal with the capacity constraint -- for example, if the next randomly chosen city would violate the capacity of the current route, start a new route. Or, if the next randomly chosen city would violate the capacity, then keep checking all the cities (in random order) until you find one that is capacity-feasible, or until you've checked all remaining cities.

Comment: I did not see your answer before I posted mine and I see we agree on the interpretation.

Comment: please check my EDIT

Answer (score 7):

Usually such statements mean that you should device a construction heuristic, which relies on some level of randomness. That is, if you run your construction procedure twice you should not (necessarily) get the same solution. I would in most cases, if not stated explicitly, expect the solution to be feasible to the problem (in your case it should probably respect the capacity constraints).

A simple, and probably not very good, randomized construction heuristic for cvrps could be something along the lines of

1. Start a new route by placing a vehicle at the depot. Let the depot be the *current node*
2. Make a list of $k\geq 1$ promising nodes that does not belong to any other routes (nodes with demand less than the residual capacity of the vehicle).
3. Generate a random number, $l$, between 1 and $k$ and extend the route with the $l$'th node from the list. Let the $l$' th node become the current node.
4. If all nodes belong to a route, return the solution.
5. If the route cannot be extended further, return to the depot and go to 1. Else go to 2.

Comment: please ckeck My EDIT

Answer (score 5):

Altough I agree with the other answers, I think its worth mentioning that **a random initial solution does not have to be feasible**.

When using (meta)heuristics, it is often the case that infeasible solutions are used in the search space, while the number of conflicts (the number of times a constraint is violated) is minimized in the cost function.

For example, this is the case in [this paper](https://app.cs.amherst.edu/%7Eccmcgeoch/cs34/papers/tabuveh2661622.pdf), where the authors develop a tabu search heuristic for the CVRP called TABUROUTE, where infeasible routes (with respect to length or capacity) are used throughout the procedure.